# java HiveClient fails select: java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive, shark-sql

I'm pretty new to Hive and HDFS, but I have managed to make a functioning HiveClient in java, that successfully connects and performs queries on my HDFS server.That is, all queries except *select* statements.

My code looks like this:

> ```
>   Statement stmt;
>   ResultSet res;
>   try {
>       stmt = con.createStatement();
>        res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from my_table");
>        while (res.next()) {
>        System.out.println(res.getString(1));
>        }
>
>       res.close();
>       stmt.close();
>       con.close();
>   } catch (SQLExceptionex) {
>       ex.printStackTrace();
>     }
> ```

When I run it, the error is this:

> java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from shark.execution.SparkTask
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:194)
>           at se.HiveClient.doQuery(HiveClient.java:56)
>           at se.HiveClient.main(HiveClient.java:82)

but if I instead do a *create table* or *show tables*, it runs perfectly. Could there be a case of missing configuration or privileges? Or something else entirely?

Any ideas as to where I may have done wrong or missed something is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a permissions issue.

Creation of tables or showing tables require hive to get metadata from its database. 
Actual selection of data requires to read a file. Check what are the permissions given to the file.

Hive would probably be querying as the hive user and hence either should be a owner of the file or should be in the right group.

This seems to be a similar issue: http://forums.pentaho.com/archive/index.php/t-89586.html

Comment: Thanks, I upped to full permissions for all user groups for the external table files, but it still fails. When I check the user grants for my user I get nothing, should this be the case? I just assumed the Hive user is the same as my user for the server, but perhaps that's not right? Do I need to set any permissions for Hive, in config files or such?